# Is there a way to save the communist deserter from execution?

Tags: metro-2033

In chapter 4 - Front Lines, you can sneak through the Communists attack on the Nazis and see a captive "Red" being executed by his superiors (if you stand there without interfering you even get a "moral point" contributing to the alternate ending). I tried saving the captive but whenever I shoot any of the executioners first, he falls dead to the ground immediately.

Is it even possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is 'No, comrade.'

Comment: @TZHX You might be right, I found out that there are a few places in that level where you *have* to trigger alertness in guards in order to get certain morale points. I tried to do a pacifist run, and you can kneecap soldiers to get past them without killing them, but their buddies usually notice and you get a snowball effect. I think sneaky games should allow you to cleverly get past the enemies, but this is quite hard in Metro.

Comment: It depends on which game you play, in the original game you cannot save him, in the Redux you can.

Comment: @NoNameProvided Playing redux and been trying this over and over. Even if I knock them out while they're facing away from the prisoner, as soon as the second guy is down the prisoner falls over dead.

Answer (score 2):

There are two executions on frontline:

- The first one is the deserter, where executioners can both be melee incapacitated before they can shoot.
- The second is the first thing you see taking the “stealth” root under the front line with a Nazi preparing to shoot three reds, his back is turned - just punch him. Afterwards The liberated red squad leader will mistake you for a ranger and wish you good luck earning the “Rescue Ranger” achievement

Comment: It depends on which game you play, in the original game you cannot save him, in the Redux you can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can indeed save him you even get an achievement/trophy for doing it. Start by stealthily killing the Nazi executioner, as if the player takes too long, the executioner can kill the prisoners. If no one noticed, proceed to stealthily kill any lone patrolling Nazis. More than likely, Artyom will eventually be seen by Nazis. Take cover and dispatch any attacking Nazi. Stay away from the prisoners or else they might be caught in the crossfire. Eventually an armed trolley will appear. Take cover and wait for the trolley, though readers should note that the trolley must be destroyed - preferably with a sticky grenade. After the trolley is destroyed and all the Nazis are dead, Artyom should return to the prisoners, one of them should be standing. Talk to the leader, he will give thanks and the player will receive the achievement, and a moral point.

Comment: This is not the prisoner being asked about